# laravelでログイン機能を実装したのですが、ログインできず、エラーになってしまいます。ログインを実現するにはどうすればよいですか？

Tags: php, laravel

laravelで勤怠管理システムを作成しており、認証機能Authを使ったログイン機能を記述しています。
mysqlを使ったデータベースには、seederファイルでユーザーのデータを登録してあります。
テストでログインを試みたのですが、ログインできず以下のようなエラーメッセージが出てしまいます。
dd();で確認したところ、$emailと$passwordには設定どおりの値が入っていました。
コードです。

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        $user = Auth::user($request);
        return view('index', ['user' => $user]);
    } else {
        return redirect('/login', ['txt' => 'ログインに失敗しました。']);
    }
}
```

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
でAuthを呼び出した先でエラーになっているようなのですが、原因がつかめません。
どなたかアドバイスを頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: TypeError Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct(): Argument #2 ($status) must be of type int, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\attendance\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php on line 233]

Comment: 迅速なご回答ありがとうございます。ifの条件式が問題ではなかったのですね。解決いたしました。助かりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージを見る限りAuth::attemptの処理は成功していると思います。
そのあとのリダイレクト処理時に引数の型が違うためエラーが出ているのではないでしょうか？

> return view('index', ['user' => $user]);

上記のコード第2引数を確認してみてください。
ユーザーの情報を配列で渡してしまっているので
ユーザーIDなど渡せば解決すると思います。

推測ですがよろしければご参考までに。